# Microsoft Access: Combining Table Fields in query to check single field in separate table

Tags: ms-access, url, redirect

I have a table called "Redirects" that has URLs in it. There are only 2 fields beyond the ID of each field: Source and Destination.  The website reads the source URL and redirects to the Destination URL when applicable. These are all entered manually, sometimes through a mass import query.

Beyond that I have a few relational tables that build products on our website.  The ones in question right now are "ParentItems", "Categories", and "ItemCategories".  URLs are constructed based off of URLs in "ParentItems", "Categories", and the relation of the IDs via the "ItemCategories" page. A typical url looks like this:

http://domain.com/category/**Categories.URL**/item/**ParentItems.URL**

Well we recently discovered that the Categories.URL parameter did not at all matter and you could access any product on the site via any category (or no category at all!). So we fixed that, but then some issues arose. Some URLs in the "Redirects" table are conflicting with the constructed URLs from the other 3 tables, causing some products to have infinite redirect loops.  Basically a secondary category is trying to take over a primary category in the URL and they are redirecting back and forth.

I am unaware of how to track these because it doesn't apply to all items, just some.

I need a way to look into the "Redirects" tables and find if a source URL exists equal to a constructed URL.  So something like:

```
IF Redirect.SourceURL == Category.URL + ParentItem.URL
```

And then it displays all redirects in which a Source URL is a primary URL for a product.

I would do this manually but we have over 12,000 products so that could take some time...

**Edit:**
[image: Relationship of the 3 tables and the redirect table]
This is the tables and how they relate. There is also a field that is called "PrimaryCategoryID" which is how the URL knows which category's url to use (if the ParentItem is in multiple categories).

SAMPLE DATA:

```
SOURCEURL: http://domain.com/category/category-1/item/item-1
TARGETURL: http://domain.com/category/category-2/item/item-1
```

In this example, the SourceURL is the URL I **DON'T** want redirecting, but it has been setup that way.  I need to use the tables above to query all instances like this.

Comment: You'll need to show some example data to go with your example code. Add a screenshot of your relationships diagram for the tables

Comment: @dbmitch I've added a screenshot and some sample data. Let me know if that is helpful or if I need to add more information.

Comment: Okay - so how does URLtext in the other tables line up and compare to sourceurl and targeturl - you show "category-1" and "item-1" as examples

Comment: category-1 would be Category.UrlText for some category. Item-1 would be ParentItems.UrlText for some item.  Category-2 is some other Category.UrlText that Item-1 is in.  In my example, I assume that Category-1 is the primary category, the one we want to be the basis of the URL.  Due to how our system works, you can use either Category-1 or Category-2.  In some cases, Category-1 redirects to Category-2 for a specific item due to the Redirects table.